# Get the class name in the @BeforeSuite annotation - TestNG - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is there a way to get the name of the class that the script was started from inside the @BeforeSuite annotation when not executed via xml file?

Doing this:

```
reportName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
```

returns the class itself that contains the @BeforeSuite annotation and this:

```
reportName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
```

returns sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorlmpl

If I execute a script directly from a separate class, I want to get that info because I am using it to name my Extent Report file name.

In case you are wondering what the code inside the @BeforeSuite annotation looks like:

```
// Set Extent Report file name from the global properties file
String reportName = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getName();
if (reportName.equals("Default suite"))
{
    reportName = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
}
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

// Initialize Extent Reports and modify the looks/output
String extentReportPath = "";
if (extent == null) {
    if (os.equals("Mac"))
    {
        extentReportPath = reportPath + "/" + project + "-" + reportName + "-" + environment + "-" + browser + "-" + timeStamp + ".html";
    }
    else if (os.equals("Windows"))
    {
        extentReportPath = reportPath + "\\" + project + "-" + reportName + "-" + environment + "-" + browser + "-" + timeStamp + ".html";
    }

    // Start new report
    extent = new ExtentReports(extentReportPath, true);
}
```

There's more to it, but this is the part pertinent to my question.

**---UPDATE---**

This was my solution:

```
// Set Extent Report file name from the global properties file
String reportName = ctx.getCurrentXmlTest().getSuite().getName();
if (reportName.equals("Default suite"))
{
    List<ITestNGMethod> allMethods = ctx.getSuite().getAllMethods();
    for (ITestNGMethod method : allMethods)
    {
        String fullMethod = method.toString();
        int indexOf = fullMethod.indexOf(".");
        reportName = fullMethod.replace(fullMethod.substring(indexOf), "");             }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass argument ITestContext to the beforesuite method. testNG will auto-inject it. This should have the information you looking for.

context.getSuite().getAllMethods -> List of TestNGMethods.getRealClass() or getTestClass().

Comment: I may have over complicated it, but this at least pointed me to where I need to go. My solution is at the bottom of my question.